# How do I delete records completely and partially from HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, delete-row, ruby-on-rails-5

I have rails models `Article` and  `User` which are associated with HABTM relation. ie an `User` can have many articles and an `Article` can belong to many `User`.
I am having hard time deleting the records. My requirement is:

- If a user deletes article that is not associated with any other user, I want to delete the article completely, meaning, delete article from `Article` table as well as from all other tables that `Article` is associated with `has_many` association(I have other models like `ArticleLinks`, `ArticleMetaTags` etc that is associated with `Article` model).
- If an `Article` is also associated with other `User` then dont delete the article completely. Just delete the `User` and `Article` association.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always implement it in a `before_destroy` callback for `ArticleUser` (the join model):

```
class ArticleUser
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user

  after_destroy do
    article.destroy if article.article_users.empty?
  end
end
```

You need to create it, if you don't have one and change the `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many`

```
class Article
  has_many :article_users
  has_many :users, through: :article_users
end

class User
  has_many :article_users
  has_many :articles, through: :article_users
end
```

That's a bit more code, but gives you more flexibility.

But I'd suggest implementing it in a some service class, something like:

```
class ArticleUsers::Delete
  attr_accessor :article_user

  def initialize(article_user)
    self.article_user = article_user
  end

  def destroy
    if article_user.destroy
      article_user.article.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

And then call it anywhere you need as `ArticleUsers::Delete.new(article_user).destroy`

And as a precaution, you can add `restrict_with_exception` to `article_users` association in `Article` class, if you don't have any explicit logic for deleting an article. It causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records.

```
class Article
  has_many :article_users, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

Comment: I don't have a model for the join table. I created it using CreateJoinTableArticleUser.. Do you suggest I create a model for join table?  Wouldn't it be a has_many :through relation in that case?

Comment: Yea, you need to create a model for article_users. `Article` is going to have many `ArticleUser` and have many `User` through article_users. And same for users. I'll update my answer.

Comment: And as I said above, I also have a ArticleLink model that is related with article with- Article has_many ArticleLink association. will this delete all the ArticleLink associated with Article when I delete the Article? How do I implement this? And thank you for your time

Comment: You need to set up destroy-dependency http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: For example, in your `Article` model, you have `has_many :article_links`. You'll need to add `dependent: :destroy` to this like `has_many :article_links, dependent: :destroy`. This will delete article_links along with the article